# The standard discrete metric is a pre-measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F$ be the ring of all finite unions of intervals of the form $(a,b]$ on $(0,1]$ and let $\delta_x$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and for $A \in F$ be the standard discrete metric.

I need to show that $\delta_x$ is a pre-measure on $F$.

Well, the domain of $\delta_x$ is a ring and it maps only to values greater or equal than 0. $\delta_x(\emptyset)=0$ since the empty set doesn't contain any elements hence $x \notin A$.

Now I need to show that

$\delta_x(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \delta_x(A_i)$

I'm not sure how I can achieve this.

Comment: What exactly are $A$ and $\delta_x$ ?

Comment: @illuminatitruthseeker Surprisingly, you did not answer the question above about $A$ and $\delta_x$, nor provide any feedback on my answer which assumed a definition of $\delta_x$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the definition of $\delta_x$ is:
$\delta_x(A) = 1$ if $x \in A$,
$\delta_x(A) = 0$ otherwise

Then, if $A_i$ are disjoint elements of $F$ (*note*: this "disjoint" condition is lacking in your question; perhaps this is what is blocking you?), we want to show that
$\delta_x(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \delta_x(A_i)$

- If $\exists j, x \in A_j, \delta_x(A_j)=1$. Then as $A_i$ are disjoint, $\forall i \ne j, x \notin A_i, \delta_x(A_i)=0$. So $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \delta_x(A_i)=1$.
  For the RHS: $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$, so $\delta_x(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) = 1$
- Otherwise $\forall i, x \notin A_i, \delta_x(A_i) = 0, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \delta_x(A_i)=0$.
  For the RHS: $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$, so $\delta_x(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) = 0$